# Profile picture should change in header when click from login page profile using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two Profile picture in login page, When i click profile 1 picture it takes me in home page and there profile picture should change as profile 1 picture in header. If i click profile 2 picture from login page it takes me in home page and there profile picture should change as profile 2 picture in header

Header Code:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Profile from '../../images/login-profile-01.jpg'
import Profile2 from '../../images/login-profile-02.jpg'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSignOut } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import Search from '../../component/Search'
import './style.scss'


const Header = () => {

    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(true)

    return (
        <div className='header-wrapper'>
            <div className='header-left'>
                <h2>SmartGo</h2>
                <nav>
                    <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="movies">Movie</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="tv-shows">Tv Shows</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="themes">Themes</NavLink>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div className='header-right'>

                <Search />

                <div className='profile-wrapper'>
                    <div className='profile'>
                        {isLoggedIn ? <img src={Profile} alt={Profile} /> : <img src={Profile2} alt={Profile2} />}
                    </div>
                    <span>Pete</span>
                </div>

                <div className="logout">
                    <NavLink to="/login">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignOut} />
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Header
```

---

Home page code

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Banner from '../../component/Banner'
import MoviePosterLeft from '../../component/Profile1/MoviePosterL'
import MoviePosterRight from '../../component/Profile1/MoviePosterR'
import './style.scss'

const Home = () => {

    const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Banner />
            <div className='movie-poster-splitted'>
                <div className='movie-poster-left'>
                    <MoviePosterLeft />
                </div>
                <div className='movie-poster-right'>
                    <div className='button-toggle'>
                        <button onClick={() => setHidden(s => !s)}>
                            Based on search recommendations
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {hidden ? <MoviePosterRight /> : ""}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Can you share code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have shared my code. Could you pls review ?